# Postgresql conditionally include distinct in query

Tags: postgresql, distinct, dynamic-sql, database-programming

Postgresql conditionally include distinct in query

Is there way to modify a query such as:

```
select distinct col1, col2  
            from our_schema.our_table
            where (id = '1001')
```

The goal is to easily activate/deactivate the distinct keyword.

Obviously, one could move it to a comment such as:

```
select col1, col2 -- distinct 
            from our_schema.our_table
            where (id = '1001')
```

Is there any easy way to do this in Postgresql?

I've seen 'dynamic SQL' in Microsoft SSMS using TSQL language.
Is there something like this for Postgresql?  Or something even simpler?

Comment: What is the condition that you would like to apply?

Comment: Also, how/from where do you run this query?

Comment: The condition is to use the "distinct" key word.  I use the 'dbeaver' database-tool as the running environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is just about code management / building SQL strings?

Insert a line break after `DISTINCT`. The only significance of white space in SQL is to [separate *tokens*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html). Other than that, line breaks are purely cosmetic - except for [standard comments starting with `--`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS) which end with the line.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       col1, col2 ...
```

-->

```sql
SELECT -- DISTINCT
       col1, col2 ...
```

Or even:

```sql
SELECT
       DISTINCT
       col1, col2 ...
```

-->

```sql
SELECT
--     DISTINCT
       col1, col2 ...
```

**Or** use [C-style block comments: `/* comment */`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS)

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 ...
```

-->

```
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ col1, col2 ...
```